# Do not want a barcode on the expanded view, but would like the card number to be displayed as large as possible, for manual keying by a store clerk

Tags: android-pay

From what I can see in the [Google Wallet Objects API](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/objects/) documentation, there are two loyalty templates from which to choose.  One has the barcode section, and the other has an image instead.  Is there any way to configure or otherwise create a third option, where a text string could be displayed in place of either a barcode or image?

Comment: Card numbers will never be displayed in full, its either 4 digits, or 6, but never the PAN part, this is due to credit card regulations. So I think your request to show the card number is impossible. Regarding manual keying, this is also not the idea behind Google Wallet, if you need to key it in, the whole idea of an API / automation is lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We currently provide two templates, loyalty1 and loyalty2.
You can use loyalty1 template that provides a barcode. For the barcode type, select textOnly.  For more information on the types of barcode provided please look at the API Reference
https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/objects/reference/v1/loyaltyobject